# Is it possible to export spatial data from database to shapefile without writing SQL manually?

Tags: shapefile, export, spatial-database, oracle-dbms

Shapefile is being imported to Oracle DB. Is there a tool to export this spatial data as a shapefile without writing any SQL (like you have to do with SQL Developer and GeoRaptor)?

**EDIT:** from all your answers I understand that there is no way for me to do action: import shapefile **X** to my database and later use some tool to export same shapefile **X** without using SQL or SQL like filtering... Unless I want to export whole layer which is not my interest.

Answer (score 1):

GDAL - specifically ogr2ogr is the proper way to go. The base syntax for exporting one table is like this:

```
$ ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" us_cities.shp OCI:scott/tiger@localhost:1521/orcl122:us_cities
```

where `localhost:1521/orcl122` is your database connection string. Note that you do not actually need to specify the output file format (as OGR assumes you want a shapefile by default):

```
$ ogr2ogr us_cities.shp OCI:scott/tiger@localhost:1521/orcl122:us_cities
```

There are many things you can do in addition.

Select the rows to export:

```
ogr2ogr us_cities.shp OCI:scott/tiger@orcl122:us_cities -where "pop90 > 500000" -progress -overwrite
```

Select the columns to export. Notice you can rename them.

```
ogr2ogr us_cities.shp OCI:scott/tiger@orcl122:us_cities -select "id, city as city_name, state_abrv" -where "pop90 > 500000" -progress -overwrite
```

Even use some pseudo-SQL syntax:

```
ogr2ogr us_cities.shp OCI:scott/tiger@orcl122:us_cities -sql "select id, location from us_cities where pop90 > 500000" -progress -overwrite
```

Finally, you can also export multiple tables:

```
ogr2ogr us_data OCI:scott/tiger@localhost:1521/orcl122:us_cities,us_counties,us_states
```

In this case, `us_data` is the name of a directory that will be created if it does not exist yet, and each table becomes a shapefile in that directory:

```
$ ls -l us_data/
total 6772
-rw-rw-r--. 1 spatial spatial   48748 Sep 21 10:16 us_cities.dbf
-rw-rw-r--. 1 spatial spatial     165 Sep 21 10:16 us_cities.prj
-rw-rw-r--. 1 spatial spatial    5560 Sep 21 10:16 us_cities.shp
-rw-rw-r--. 1 spatial spatial    1660 Sep 21 10:16 us_cities.shx
-rw-rw-r--. 1 spatial spatial 1218031 Sep 21 10:16 us_counties.dbf
-rw-rw-r--. 1 spatial spatial     165 Sep 21 10:16 us_counties.prj
-rw-rw-r--. 1 spatial spatial 4605788 Sep 21 10:16 us_counties.shp
-rw-rw-r--. 1 spatial spatial   25940 Sep 21 10:16 us_counties.shx
-rw-rw-r--. 1 spatial spatial  156889 Sep 21 10:16 us_states.dbf
-rw-rw-r--. 1 spatial spatial     165 Sep 21 10:16 us_states.prj
-rw-rw-r--. 1 spatial spatial  837388 Sep 21 10:16 us_states.shp
-rw-rw-r--. 1 spatial spatial     548 Sep 21 10:16 us_states.shx
```

And not specifying any table name will export all (spatial) tables from the schema you connect as:

```
ogr2ogr us_data OCI:scott/tiger@localhost:1521/orcl122
```

**EDIT**:

Forgot to mention that you can use the same selection techniques (columns, rows, pseudo-sql) also when you import from shapefile (or from any other format).

Answer (score 1):

If you use [geoserver](http://geoserver.org/), this is quite user friendly to extract shapefile from your Oracle database or any other spatial data source. You need to connect geoserver with oracle database [(connection guidelines)](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/database/oracle.html) then you can export data by using layer preview -> shapefiles.

In case you need to filter your data or choose selected columns, you can create SQL views or apply filters in WFS request.

Comment: We ended up using geoserver-> layer preview -> shapefiles even though it exports whole layer. Thank you for pointing out this method.

Comment: Filters are available, see http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/. If you need to choose few columns you can create SQL view.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from your question if you are importing or exporting the data. In either case [`ogr2ogr`](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) will solve the problem for you. Providing that what you want is all the data then there should be no need for any SQL.

The [BostonGIS cheat sheet](http://www.bostongis.com/?content_name=ogr_cheatsheet) gives some examples with PostGIS but [Oracle](http://www.gdal.org/drv_oci.html) should be much the same syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am importing shape files but I am interested in posibility to export them later.